# Is there a way to solve this ValueError in my django app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I’ve created a school database intranet app for schools using the Django framework. I’m trying to get the teacher to update the registered student’s assessment within the Teachers account. I've used ForeignKey relations to relate the Student account with the Assessment models but I seem to be getting this

```
ValueError at /Teacher/Grade9_classA_teacher/Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview2b2371fd-7e64-413a-adcd-43c8b68cd9d3/
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Grade_9_Student: account1>]>": "Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1.user_Name" must be a "Account" instance.
```

I don’t know what this means, somebody please help solve my problem.
This is my assessment model codes

```
from admin_app.models import Account
#Assessment models
    class Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assessment_1(models.Model):
            user_Name=models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
            T1_A1_Maths_Title=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
            T1_A1_Maths_Desc=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
            T1_A1_Maths_is_Test=models.BooleanField(default=False)
            T1_A1_Maths_Marks=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
            T1_A1_Maths_OutOfMarks=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
            T1_A1_Maths_DatePosted=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date posted', auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my assessment form codes
#Forms.py

```
from Student.student_views.Grade9_std_views.Grade9_models import Term_11_math_assesment, Grade_9_Student
#Term 1 
#Maths assesment 1
class Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_form(ModelForm):
    T1_A1_Maths_is_Test=forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    class Meta:
        model=Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1
        fields=['T1_A1_Maths_Title', 'T1_A1_Maths_Desc', 'T1_A1_Maths_is_Test', 'T1_A1_Maths_Marks', 'T1_A1_Maths_OutOfMarks', 'T1_A1_Maths_DatePosted']
```

This is my main user model codes

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import uuid
# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

#from Teacher.Teacher_views.Grade9_views.Grd9_assesment_models import Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email is not pressent")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("username is not pressent")
        user=self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user=self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username           
            )
        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    #Identification details
    id=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email=models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #Code test
    

    
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email',]
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('headmin:Grade_9_Teacher_list_details', args=[str(self.id)])

    objects=MyAccountManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
#Student models
class Grade_9_Student(Account):
    #T1_A1_Maths_Marks=models.ForeignKey(Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Grade_9_student_classA_A=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Grd9_ClsA_std_profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='Student/Grade9/Grd9ClassA/Grd9ClsAProPic/')
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_no=models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Resident=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

#views.py

This is the function code that I use to try to attach Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assessment_1 to the

```
def Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview(request, pk):
    std=Grade_9_Student.objects.filter(id=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.T1_A1_Maths_Title=std
            instance.save()
            return redirect('Teacher:Grade_9_students_clsA_lists')
    else:
        form=Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_form()
    return render(request, 'Grade9Teach/Tgrd9A/Upload_assesments_subjects/upload_assesments.html', {'form':form})
```

This is my url code

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('Grade9_classA_teacher/', include(([
        path('', Grd9_ClsA_Teach_view.Grade9_classA_teacher, name='Grade9_classA_teacher'),
        path('searchResult_view_grd9_A/', Grd9_ClsA_Teach_view.searchResult_view_grd9_A.as_view(), name='searchResult_view_grd9_A'),       
            #Term 1 assesments
            #MATH
        path('Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view<uuid:pk>/', Grd9_ClsA_assesment_views.Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view.as_view(), name='Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view'),
        path('Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view<int:pk>/', Grd9_ClsA_assesment_views.Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view.as_view(), name='Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_view'),
        path('Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview<uuid:pk>/', Grd9_ClsA_assesment_views.Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview, name='Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview'),      
    ], 'Teacher'))),
]
```

#web browser
ValueError

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Grade_9_Student: account1>]>": "Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1.user_Name" must be a "Account" instance.
```

#console logs

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 10, 2020 - 14:35:09
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'SchoolDatabaseTrial.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /Teacher/Grade9_classA_teacher/Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview2b2371fd-7e64-413a-adcd-43c8b68cd9d3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Envs\core\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Envs\core\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Envs\core\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\SchoolDatabaseTrial\Teacher\Teacher_views\Grade9_views\Grd9_ClsA_views\Grd9_ClsA_std\Grd_9_Marks_forms_and_views\Grd9_ClsA_assesment_views.py", line 71, in Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview
    instance.user_Name=Grade_9_Student.objects.filter(id=pk)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Envs\core\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 219, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Grade_9_Student: account1>]>": "Grade_9_models_math_Term1_assesment_1.user_Name" must be a "Account" instance.
[10/Jul/2020 14:35:15] "POST /Teacher/Grade9_classA_teacher/Grd9_ClsA_math_Term_1_assesment1_createview2b2371fd-7e64-413a-adcd-43c8b68cd9d3/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81054
```

Please help me, how do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample is different from your traceback. In your traceback, you have:

```
instance.user_Name=Grade_9_Student.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

Because you are using `filter()`, you are attempting to assign a QuerySet that contains a single Account instance in it to a field that expects an Account instance. You can change this to one of the following:

```
# Recommended since you're querying by a unique PK value
instance.user_Name=Grade_9_Student.objects.get(id=pk)

# The same as above, but with extra steps
instance.user_Name=Grade_9_Student.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```